# Uploading laravel project to server using php version 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2 and the php version is php 7 , now i need to upload my project on a server  , should the server support php 7??
or just support the php version used by laravel 5.2  , (PHP >= 5.5.9)??

Comment: This depends if you used anything specific to PHP7, I'm not sure the new features off hand that were added that were not in 5.5.  For the most part you only have to worry about things that are new, or added to 7.  Although I sort of recall a change to either array_walk, or array_map ... lol ... essentially the sever needs to support whatever version the code needs to support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're not using any php 7 features in your code, it has to work, since Laravel's 5.2 minimal PHP version is 5.5.9.

Still.. Make sure your server satisfies all [requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation#server-requirements)